# Make a firstResponder UIView by containing another firstResponder (a UITextView)

Tags: uikit, uiresponder

I have a `UIView` subclass (`MyView`) that contains a `UITextView`. I want `MyView` to use `UITextView` for all `UIResponder` methods like so:

```
@implementation MyView

- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
  return _textView.canBecomeFirstResponder
}
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
  return [_textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
- (BOOL)canResignFirstResponder {
  return [_textView canResignFirstResponder];
}
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
  // UIResponder documentation says [super resignFirstResponder]
  // must be called somewhere in this method
  BOOL superResignedFirstResponder = [super resignFirstResponder];
  if (superResignedFirstResponder) {
    return [_textView resignFirstResponder];
  } else {
    return NO;
  }
}
- (BOOL)isFirstResponder {
  return [_textView isFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

However, as I'm reading through [Apple's Event Delivery: The Responder Chain documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH4-SW2), I think this may be an incorrect implementation. I can't find any documentation or posts about how to create a `UIResponder` with another `UIResponder`.

`UIKit` has a notion of exactly 1 `firstResponder`, so when `MyView` handles `-becomeFirstResponder` and returns `YES`, it seems reasonable for `UIKit` to think `MyView` is the `firstResponder`. However, since I in turn call `-[UITextView becomeFirstResponder]` within `-[MyView becomeFirstResponder]`, one of the two must win and one must lose. Which wins and which loses? If `UITextView` is the `firstResponder`, then why should `-[MyView isFirstResponder]` ever return `YES`?

Does anyone have any advice? Is my above implementation correct?

Answer (score 0):

Though I found [other evidence that people solved this problem the same way](https://github.com/colloquy/colloquy/blob/main/Mobile/Views/CQChatInputBar.m#L175). This implementation is causing me problems. TLDR: I think you're just not supposed to compose `UIResponder` objects.

My bug:

1. A consumer calls a method on `MyView`, and `MyView` programmatically calls `-[UITextView becomeFirstResponder]`. No one ever taps on `MyView`'s internal `UITextView`.
2. A consumer wants to dismiss the keyboard. We can verify that `UITextView` is the `firstResponder` because the private API `-[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow firstResponder]` returns `UITextView`.
3. A consumer calls `[UIApplication sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil]`, but this call returns `NO`. While this call is made, `UIKit` doesn't call `-[UITextView canPerformAction:withSender:]` or `-[UITextView targetForAction:withSender:]`.

However, if instead:

1. the user taps on `MyView`'s `UITextView`
2. A consumer wants to dismiss the keyboard. We can verify that `UITextView` is the `firstResponder` because the private API `-[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow firstResponder]` returns `UITextView`.
3. A consumer calls `[UIApplication sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil]`, and now this call returns `YES`. While this call is made, `UIKit` calls `-[UITextView canPerformAction:withSender:]` and `-[UITextView targetForAction:withSender:]` as expected, and then of course calls `-[UITextView resignFirstResponder]`, which succeeds.

I have no idea why in the first case `[UIApplication sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil]` doesn't delegate to `UITextView` properly, but I have to assume that since `-[MyView becomeFirstResponder]` without delegating to `[super becomeFirstResponder]` as the docs say, something got messed up. I think you're just not supposed to compose `UIResponder` objects.

**--EDIT--**

I still don't know for sure what's wrong, but I discovered that I have multiple `UIWindow`s in my app, and I've heard from People That Know™ that multi-windowed apps can have occasional `firstResponder` issues.